# I need advice in how to aproach setting up a webserver

Tags: javascript, networking, frontend, backend, web-development-server

For a school group project we're asked to make a sort of scheduling application, we are free to set it up any way we want but i dont have any experience in web developing.

For the backend we've decided on java for the logic and a mongodb database but i'm exploring options for frontend development so far javascript has peeked my interest but i need some directions for what to look into

I was wondering if i could make a connection between javascript (if there are no more intresting options) and the java program running on my (virtual) machine and if i could host a webserver myself or need to look for a hosting service

Lessons on this topic start following next week but i want to make a head start and have a  n idea were to look into

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: if the application is a web application, then actually you have no choice but to use javascript and the question is how and what framework and that depends on how big of an app we're talking about. if it is not required to be web i'd recommend to stay in the real of java and use SWING interfaces, not as nice and clean as html but you can use drag&drop solutions to make it easily. if you have any more question feel free to @ me and i'll respond.

Comment: @chawki challadi Thanks for your answer! i think ill stick with javascript then, it won't be that big of a program as +/- 50 people (theoretically) will interact with it and only a fraction of that at the same time but we'd like to access it as www.<nonameyet>.whatEverExtensionIsCheap. My main concern is how it should be hosted and how to get requests from javascript to our machine runing our software.

Comment: @chawk challadia, thanks! i've added you :)

Comment: @chawki challadia sorry i misspeled your name but i've added you!